# Determine a subspace in R^5

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble with this question:

For (c) obviously I can prove that by the "Closed under scalar multiplication"
But the other two I am a bit confused. Hope someone might shed some light on this.Thank you.

For each of the following subsets $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$
, determine if $S$ is a subspace. If yes, prove so (for
example by checking the three properties). If no, show by example that one of the properties
fails.

(a) $S$ the set of all vectors with all entries rational numbers.

(b) $S = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^5
|v · (4, −1007, 0, −1, 356) = 0\}$

(c) $S = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^5
|v · v ≥ 0\}$

Comment: For the first one: Will a vector with rational numbers as entries stay a vector with rational numbers as entries after multiplying by, say, $e$? For the second one, just check the three properties, this shouldn't be too difficult. The third one should be easy as well, and actually equals the whole of $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: @B.Pasternak I guess no? So that is an explicit example that counters it right?

Comment: Certainly; let's say we take $v=(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)$, then $2e\cdot v=(e,e,e,e,e)$, and $e$ is not a rational number. Can you figure out the other two?

Comment: @B.Pasternak Yeah I think I definitely understand it now. Just need to do the "paperwork" lol. But thank you very much for the prompt response!

Comment: No problem, I have added an answer so this question doesn't remain unanswered, accept if you feel so.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Sure. Just did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this gets answered:

a) No, a simple counterexample is $(1,0,0,0,0)$ and the scalar $e\in\mathbb{R}$.

b) As $0\cdot v=0$ for any $v\in\mathbb{R}^5$, zero is in there. For $v,w\in S$ we have $(v+w)\cdot(4,-1007,0,-1,356)=v\cdot(4,-1007,0,-1,356)+w\cdot(4,-1007,0,-1,356)=0+0=0$. Any scalar multiple comes out of the dot product, so $\lambda v\cdot(-4,1007,0,-1,356)=0$, hence this is a subspace.

c) For any $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $v\cdot v\ge0$ and $v\cdot v=0$ iff $v=0$, so this is a subspace which is equal to $\mathbb{R}^5$.